# Create element range index by MarkLogic REST API - Not creating element range in server , No error

Tags: curl, marklogic

I am executing this CURL command to create element range index under Database : Schemas in MarkLogic.

Below is the CURL command :

```
CURL -X POST --digest -u admin:admin@123 -H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
"range-element-indexes":[
    {"scalar-type":"dateTime", 
     "namespace-uri":"", 
     "localname":"test",      
     "collation":"", 
     "range-value-positions":"",
     "invalid-values":"reject", 
    }
 ]
}' \
http://127.0.0.1:8002/manage/v2/databases/Schemas/properties


I am getting no error , but I see no element range created in the server.
```

Comment: I would expect that you would get an HTTP 404 resposne when you do a POST to that endpoint, and then if you do a PUT you would get an HTTP 400 MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOAD

Comment: Is it really your intent to put a range index on the schemas database? That seems unlikely. You would normally put them on your content database

Comment: I agree with Mads, you should get an error.  And I tested and I indeed got a 404 then a 400 (I also had a 400 because of the last comma, which is not valid JSON.)  I strongly suggest you to make sure the error is propagated correctly to you, whatever means you use to execute cURL, before going any further with the APIs (esp. the Manage API.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and investigation to help . I am running the full process in a container and now able to test the curl executions within the container bash terminal. Which helped me to debug the issue as suggested by Mads This issue is solved now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. The [/manage/v2/databases/{id|name}/properties](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/%5Bid-or-name%5D/properties) supports **GET** and **PUT** verbs, not **POST**. So, you are going to want to change the **POST** to **PUT**.
2. In the JSON payload the property `range-element-indexes` should be `range-element-index` (singular, not plural). It's a little confusing, but the differences between the XML format and the JSON format is that in XML there is a containing element called `range-element-indexes` that has a sequence of `range-element-index` children, but in JSON there is just a `range-element-index` property that has an array of objects. The documentation listing the properties is modeled from the XML and schema, not the JSON payloads.

After making those adjustments, I was able to **PUT** and create the range-index on my local instance.